# "Expression cannot contain lambda expressions" - Exception

Tags: c#, linq, list

I tried to select and split a list from list of object like this :

```
GlobalV.LatestNews.Select(x => x.Source.Split('/').ToList().FindLast(y=> y!="")).ToList();
```

but I got an exception in `FindLast(y=> y!="")` said

> expression cannot contain lambda expressions

I don't understand why !!!? I tried `RemoveAll` and ..etc but I got the same exception in each time.

Comment: Are you trying to run this in Visual Studio debugger's watch/quickwatch windows? if so it doesn't support lambda expressions.

Comment: No it is not the same question. Of course I checked and I debugged it and I don't have anything empty !!!

Comment: The exception is saying Expression. Normal Linq-to-objects doesn't use expressions, but lambda's which are compiled into the code. What enumerable type is your LatestNews? Is it an IQueryable, and is GlobalV a context? Is there EF or L2S involved here?

Comment: Could you answer @Nightwish91 's question? Are you trying to do it from one of the debug windows? Or is this happening when you try to compile your code?

Comment: "I got an exception" - post the **full details** of the exception you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it doesn't directly solve your problem, why don't you let the Split method handle the part you are trying to solve through the lambda expressions at the end?

```
var lastNonEmptySourceEntries = LatestNews.Select(x => x.Source.Split( new []{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).LastOrDefault());
```